Parse header files not found
I've installed parse-sdk-ios-osx via the Swift Package Manager.
When I was using Xcode 14 and Xcode 15 I did not have any issues. When I started using Xcode 16.0 I get the following errors:

I include Parse in my ObjC code with:
@import ParseCore;

Any ideas/suggestions?
jb

A few things: is this a new project with a freshly installed SPM? Can you update the question with which SPM options were selected when the package was added? Is this pure ObjC?

Xcode 16 has made some changes related to bitcode. You need to update the package version or just remove this package and add back in xcode16

Issue was resolved by removing old Parse version, 4.0.1, and installing new 4.1.1. Thanks for the tip.
